# There is an issue with Select in my SQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select

The scoreboard has not been showing up in the rightHighScore div. It's just not showing anything. I'm making a high score board for my javascript snake game. So is there anything wrong with my MYSQL code here?

```
<html>

    <link href='style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <!-- Lets make a simple snake game -->
    <canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="snake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <?php $score = "<script>document.write(score)</script>"?>

    <p id = 'demo'>Your Final Score: <script>score</script></p>

    <div id = 'right'>
       <div id = 'rightForm'>
          <form action="highscoreregistry.php" method="post">
             <input type="hidden" name="score" id="score">


          </form>
       </div>
       <div id = 'rightHighScore' style = 'size:9px;'>
        <?php
    $servername = "-";
    $username = "-";
    $password = "-";
    $dbname = "-";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Name, Score, Date FROM snakehiscore";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["Name"]."</td><td>".$row["Score"]." ".$row["Date"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
   </div>
</div>


</html>
```

Comment: MySQL version is 5.1 on 000webhost.com, and PHP is 5.2

Comment: What errors are you getting?  I would think a query of high scores would also need to include an `ORDER BY` clause no?

Comment: Check your http servers error log file. It tells you exactly what is wrong in what line of what script. Makes more sense than trying to _guess_ what might be wrong. You _cannot_ develop php without monitoring that log file (unless you are _really_ fond of guessing games).

Comment: If you mean it's not outputting anything, does that mean it's not showing `0 results` and/or the tables at all? In any case: Take a look at [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), then check your logs for errors, as already stated above.

Comment: Do you get nothing displayed full stop or '0 results', do you get the table headers show up but no additional rows? Is there data in your sql table?

Comment: Nothing displays whatsoever, and I have no idea where I would find this HTTP file. I'm just starting again with Web development and haven't done it in a long time.

Comment: @TriangleAceStudio Then add [`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to the top of your file, along with error-reporting as suggested above. It will tell you which errors occur. If you get any fatal errors, PHP will stop executing alltogether.

Comment: @Qirel Nothing happened/changed.

Comment: It is a PHP file, yes? And you have something to run PHP on, such as Apache or something? What happens if you do `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>`, does it print to the screen?

Comment: Add an if `if (!$results) { echo mysqli_error() }` and see what comes up

Comment: @Matt I am testing this now.

Comment: @Matt I added a semicolon to the echo cause at first it did not work, got an error. After that, I recieved this error: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/a9220077/public_html/snake/index.php on line 45

Comment: But then after highlighting it to copy and paste it, the table showed up..... Without the score though. (I had specified the font color to be white, no idea why the font was black)

Comment: I feel so stupid lol

Comment: change it to `if (!$results) { echo "Error:" .  $conn->error); }` as for the table all being in white. Always check your chrome inspector or alternative dev tools to see what is being outputted :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks, a lot!

Comment: $conn not $mysqli keep using the default but you used $conn haha sorry!

Comment: It's cool! Thanks again!

Comment: It just said 'Error:' and that's it. You can see it here: http://bobby.host56.com/snake/

Comment: Click cancel when it asks to submit score, not finished with that yet.

Answer (score -4):

1. Add a semicolon to the query! So:

   $sql = "SELECT Name, Score, Date FROM snakehiscore;";

2.Instead of using this:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

try this if you have mysqli installed:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this wouldn't make a difference at all. The object oriented version does the same as the procedural one. And the semicolon doesn't matter, since it's just one query.

Comment: 1st version is OOP style of MySQLi,  2nd version is procedural. That's not the issue here.